# Task 'prepareReleaseUnitTestDependencies' not found in project ':app'

Tags: android, gradle

I'm getting this error in console while building my android project. Please help me understand this.

Messages:

Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'prepareReleaseUnitTestDependencies' not found in project ':app'.
- Try:
  Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Gradle:

```
buildscript 
{

    repositories {

        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

//subprojects are added here
project(':external:calendar') {
    apply plugin: 'android-library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 25
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }
        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
}

project(':external:colorpicker') {
    apply plugin: 'android-library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 25
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }
        }
    }
}

project(':external:datetimepicker') {
    apply plugin: 'android-library'

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 25
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }
        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
}

project(':external:timezonepicker') {
    apply plugin: 'android-library'

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 25
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
            }
        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
}

project(':external:chips') {
    apply plugin: 'android-library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 25
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }
        }


        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile project(':external:calendar')
    compile project(':external:colorpicker')
    compile project(':external:datetimepicker')
    compile project(':external:timezonepicker')
    compile project(':external:chips')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src', 'external/ex/common/java'] // NOTE: this includes external/ex/common/java!
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    /*
     * To sign release build, create file gradle.properties in ~/.gradle/ with this content:
     *
     * signingStoreLocation=/home/key.store
     * signingStorePassword=xxx
     * signingKeyAlias=alias
     * signingKeyPassword=xxx
     */
    if (project.hasProperty('signingStoreLocation') &&
            project.hasProperty('signingStorePassword') &&
            project.hasProperty('signingKeyAlias') &&
            project.hasProperty('signingKeyPassword')) {
        println "Found sign properties in gradle.properties! Signing build…"

        signingConfigs {
            release {
                storeFile file(signingStoreLocation)
                storePassword signingStorePassword
                keyAlias signingKeyAlias
                keyPassword signingKeyPassword
            }
        }

        buildTypes.release.signingConfig = signingConfigs.release
    } else {
        buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}

task customClean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
clean.dependsOn customClean
```

Comment: post your error log

Comment: Show your build.gradle

Comment: Please find the error log and top level gradle in the edited code.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you need to delete " `-x prepareReleaseUnitTestDependencies`" from :

> Setting / build,execution, deployment/ compiler/ command-line Options

.